# How do I print these json values with php

Tags: php, json

How do I loop through this json with PHP and only extract/print the 3 digit numbers under "DataPoints"?

My goal is to at some point take those 3 digit numbers and then add them all up and get the average.

```
[
    {
        "MetricName": "payment_cnt.STATE.1s",
        "Tags": {
            "environment": "P",
            "pymtver": "2",
            "dataset": "tpv"
        },
        "DataPoints": [
            [
                1569711341,
                236
            ],
            [
                1569711342,
                205
            ],
            [
                1569711343,
                205
            ],
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid (I presume it's a cut/paste and you removed part of it), once that is corrected this will work: https://3v4l.org/Le8EZ

Comment: Thanks Nick. You're right, I cut off the bottom of the JSON but your solution works for me. I was able to print 'MetricName' and 'Tag' but was struggling to loop through 'DataPoints'. Your solutions makes sense and I understand. Thanks again internet stranger!

Comment: No worries. I always like to offer a solution (or at least a good pointer to one) when I close a question as a dupe...